# Python Script for UDDF/XML to CSV

Tags: python, xml

I wrote the following script to take a UDDF XML file to CSV. Is there a better way to do this using just regex, or a better way using ElementTree? My method for returning pieces of the floating point numbers and then rejoining with a "." during output seems really crude.

Here's my python script:

```
import re 

uddf_file = open("c:/temp/python/uddf_to_csv/input.xml", "r")
csv_file = open("c:/temp/python/uddf_to_csv/output.csv", "x")

while True:

    uddf_line = uddf_file.readline()
    uddf_line.rstrip('\r\n')

    depth_val = re.search("depth", uddf_line)
    if depth_val: depth_val_num = re.findall(r'\d+', uddf_line)
    if depth_val: csv_file.write(depth_val_num[0] + "." + depth_val_num[1] + ",")

   time_val = re.search("divetime", uddf_line)
   if time_val: time_val_num = re.findall(r'\d+', uddf_line)
   if time_val: csv_file.write(time_val_num[0] + "." + time_val_num[1] + ",")

   temp_val = re.search("temperature", uddf_line)
   if temp_val: temp_val_num = re.findall(r'\d+', uddf_line)
   if temp_val: csv_file.write(temp_val_num[0] + "." + temp_val_num[1] + "\n")   

   if not uddf_line: break;

uddf_file.close()
csv_file.close()
```

Example UDDF file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<uddf xmlns="http://www.streit.cc/uddf/3.2/" version="3.2.0">
  <generator>
    <name>awu2uddf</name>
    <manufacturer id="Foghead">
      <name>Doug Junkins</name>
    </manufacturer>
    <version>1.1(3)</version>
  </generator>
  <diver>
    <owner id="owner">
      <personal>
        <firstname/>
        <lastname/>
      </personal>
      <equipment>
        <divecomputer id="81333b11">
          <name>Apple Watch Ultra</name>
           <model>Apple Watch Ultra</model>
        </divecomputer>
      </equipment>
    </owner>
    <buddy/>
  </diver>
  <divesite/>
  <gasdefinitions/>
  <profiledata>
    <repetitiongroup id="2023-04-12T17:02:08Z">
      <dive id="2023-04-12T17:02:08Z">
        <informationbeforedive>
          <datetime>2023-04-12T10:02:08-0700</datetime>
        </informationbeforedive>
        <samples>
          <waypoint>
            <depth>2.086</depth>
            <divetime>2.520</divetime>
            <temperature>293.3</temperature>
          </waypoint>
          <waypoint>
            <depth>3.322</depth>
            <divetime>5.150</divetime>
            <temperature>293.3</temperature>
          </waypoint>
          <waypoint>
            <depth>1.101</depth>
            <divetime>2263.999</divetime>
            <temperature>293.2</temperature>
          </waypoint>
        </samples>
      </dive>
    </repetitiongroup>
  </profiledata>
</uddf>
```

Comment: Please don't parse XML with regex. That isn't the tool for the task. Use `lxml`/`beautifulsoup`/some other XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

Use a powershell script

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test1.xml"

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)
$ns = $doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace()
$waypoints = $doc.Descendants($ns + 'waypoint')

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($waypoint in $waypoints)
{
   $depth = $waypoint.Element($ns + 'depth').Value
   $divetime = $waypoint.Element($ns + 'divetime').Value
   $temperature = $waypoint.Element($ns + 'temperature').Value

   $newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
    depth = $depth
    divetime  = $divetime
    temperature = $temperature
   }
   $table.Add($newRow)
}
$table | format-Table
$table | Export-CsV -Path $outputFilename -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

With pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

xml="""copy your xml here ..."""

df = pd.read_xml(xml,'.//xmlns:waypoint', namespaces={"xmlns": "http://www.streit.cc/uddf/3.2/"})
print(df)
df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
   depth  divetime  temperature
0  2.086     2.520        293.3
1  3.322     5.150        293.3
2  1.101  2263.999        293.2
```